# JS framework platform to develop video-heavy app for android/ios/web

Tags: android, web-apps, software-development, javascript, ios

There are many JavaScript framework to develop multiplatform apps. I need one which is focused on (or at least very good at) video capture and processing.

Requirements:

- JavaScript-based framework
- Generated app works on Android and iOS
- Can also be used to power a website and a web API
- Free, ideally open source

## Details

I want to develop an app for capturing and processing videos using smartphone or web camera. As a new comer in this field can you suggest a good javascript platform (if available) for creating this kind of app. I have heard about **backbone.js**, **node.js**, **angular.js** etc . But i really don’t know which is good for my purpose. Basically I want to create an app which is similar to **vine.com** capturing videos from camera with a time limit of 1 minute (currently wants to  create and save video files locally in phone or computer and not to publish in a website)

Comment: Please add discrete identifiable requirements to your post.

Comment: can you please elaborate what you meant by `discrete` . I want to create a vine like application but currently i am not looking for publishing it in web but save as a local video file

Comment: Do you want to use the same technology for the mobile apps and for the website?

Comment: Your question was about to get closed, so I made it on-topic.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Thanks for editing and making the question on-topic.. I want to use it for both web and mobile apps